# Streaming stdout from DLL to webclient

Tags: asp.net, c++, redirect, native, stdout

I've got a DLL which can generates an image based on a certain input. The image can be exported to a file or to stdout.
I want to create a web application which will show this image, so I created a handler which perform a DLL import an shows the image.
**This works the first time, but then for some really strange reason I can't read the second time the output from stdout using an AnonymousPipeServerStream.**

Code:

```
Dim oContext As HttpContext = CType(oOBject, HttpContext)
Dim iLength As Integer = 0

Using oServer As New IO.Pipes.AnonymousPipeServerStream(IO.Pipes.PipeDirection.Out, IO.HandleInheritability.None, 6562038)
    Dim defaultHandle As IntPtr = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE)
    SetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE, CType(oServer.SafePipeHandle.DangerousGetHandle, IntPtr))
    Dim x = Err.LastDllError
    Try
        Dim i As Integer = fnImageConverter() 'THIS IS THE DLL FUNCTION WHICH WRITES TO STDOUT
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try

    Using oClient As New IO.Pipes.AnonymousPipeClientStream(IO.Pipes.PipeDirection.In, oServer.ClientSafePipeHandle)
        Using oReader As New IO.BinaryReader(oClient)
            oServer.Flush()
            While (iLength < 6562038) 'TODO, size to read.

                Dim aValue As Byte = oReader.ReadByte()
                oContext.Response.OutputStream.WriteByte(aValue)
                iLength += 1
            End While
        End Using
    End Using
    SetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE, defaultHandle)
    x = Err.LastDllError

    oServer.DisposeLocalCopyOfClientHandle()
    oServer.Close()
End Using
```

This works perfect the first time. The second time (e.g. when client hits the refresh button) it hangs on the native code behind "oReader.ReadByte()".

I hope that someone can help me. I'm really looking a long time and can't find the correct sollution.
I can modify the DLL, but slightly. I have to use a point compatible with (FILE *) like stdout, and I has to be very fast...

And some other question (for which I'm afraid for the answer):
By redirecting the stdout to a pipe stream, is this only for the currentThread or for all threads. In other words: if to browsers call this handler at exactly the same time, how will the system react? Every call is performed in a separate thread...

This is driving me crazy.

Regards,

Kristof